# mvn clean install in arch linux produces many errors

Tags: java, linux, maven, archlinux

I am using Arch Linux and jdk version 9 and apache Maven 3.5.2

I followed this link https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial to setup apps.

But when I ran command

```
mvn clean install
```

The installation process runs and suddenly it gives a bunch of errors as shown
[image]

[image]

I searched the link that is provided in the error but it did not help.
Also I googled things that are similar to my error but things didn't get sorted out. I am very much new to these things.
Please somebody provide me solution for this.

As suggested I have edited my post by providing `-X` and     -e

commands in the mvn and those errors are below

```
mnv -e :
[shivam@shivam get-started-java]$ mvn -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.191 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-15T08:44:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

And on running `mvn-X`

```
[shivam@shivam ~]$ mvn -X
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (NON-CANONICAL_2017-10-25T13:09:52+03:00_root; 2017-10-25T15:39:52+05:30)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.3-1-arch", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/shivam/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /opt/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/shivam/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/shivam/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/shivam/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-15T08:47:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

And As stated above I am using jdk version 9 .

Comment: try using newest version of  `maven-enforcer-plugin`

Comment: how to use that ??

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html

Comment: not worked same error occurring again and again

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the full stack trace and logging? Re-run with the `-X` and `-e` flags and include the full text of the exception, not pictures. Also, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I have given the necessary details as you mentioned

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I think this question is not off-topic because Maven is a development tool : *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**. You may be able to get help on Super User."*

Comment: Based on the output you have to use a newer version of maven-enforcer-plugin..3.0.0-M1 would be the most recent version...And the output where you stated to use JDK 9 you have to give something like `mvn clean package` ...and not only `mvn -e` cause Maven expects something to execute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of research on this topic. And the result I found out is that there is incompatibility of versions of java and maven that causes this problem.
Currently I was using jdk version 9.
The Solution to this problem may be change the default jdk version to jdk 8

Comment: The root cause of the issue is that you haven't used the most recent version of [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) cause this ancient version (1.0.0) does not support Java 9...You have to use `3.0.0-M1` ....Apart from that your result of your research is simply wrong, cause Maven including the most recent versions of plugins work fine with JDK 9...

Comment: I have used  maven-enforcer-plugin version 3.0.0 but it did not worked with jdk 9

Comment: You can't use maven-enforcer-plugin version 3.0.0 cause it does not exist. `3.0.0-M1` is the version. And saying `it did not work...` what does that mean ? Do you have log outputs etc. Best would be to file in a [jira issue on the project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MENFORCER) so someone can take look...

Comment: I was saying about the version `3.0.0-M1` and saying it did not work means i have used the above stated version in my project but running the command `mvn clean install` did not worked as it showed the same problem as stated in my question